# Centos 7, почему не запускается openvpn клиент?

Tags: centos, openvpn

Пытаюсь установить клиент openvpn на centos7:

```
# systemctl start openvpn@openvpn.service
Job for openvpn@openvpn.service failed. See 'systemctl status 
openvpn@openvpn.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

# systemctl status openvpn@openvpn.service

openvpn@openvpn.service - OpenVPN service openvpn

Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@openvpn.service; enabled)

Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2015-07-15 16:25:46 FET; 14s ago

Process: 9523 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --writepid /var/run/openvpn/%i.pid --cd /etc/openvpn/ --config %i.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 15 16:25:46 erp systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service openvpn...

Jul 15 16:25:46 erp systemd[1]: openvpn@openvpn.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1

Jul 15 16:25:46 erp systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN service openvpn.

Jul 15 16:25:46 erp systemd[1]: Unit openvpn@openvpn.service entered failed state.
```

В чем может быть причина проблемы?

Comment: как обычно, selinux?

Comment: SELINUX=disabled

Comment: В логе openvpn:
Options error: --writepid fails with '/var/run/openvpn/openvpn.pid': No such file or directory
Options error: Please correct these errors.
Use --help for more information.

Comment: вероятно, каталог `/var/run/openvpn` не существует. создайте: `# mkdir -p /var/run/openvpn`.

Comment: создал, запустил еще раз. в логе: Wed Jul 15 16:51:00 2015 OpenVPN 2.3.7 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 9 2015
Wed Jul 15 16:51:00 2015 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013, LZO 2.06
Wed Jul 15 16:51:00 2015 WARNING: using --pull/--client and --ifconfig together is probably not what you want
Wed Jul 15 16:51:00 2015 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled. See openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.

Comment: Wed Jul 15 16:51:00 2015 WARNING: file '/etc/openvpn/keys/usererp.key' is group or others accessible
Wed Jul 15 16:51:00 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->131072] S=[212992->131072]
Wed Jul 15 16:51:00 2015 failed to find GID for group nogroup
Wed Jul 15 16:51:00 2015 Exiting due to fatal error

Comment: *failed to find GID for group nogroup* — вероятно, где-то в конфигурации упомянута эта несуществующая группа. замените на сущствующую нужную.

Comment: так и ест. открываю vi /etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf, закомментирываю и пользователя и группу #user nobody #group nogroup. пробую запуститься. запустился. статус - активен. но pid прочитать не может. это критично?

Comment: systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service openvpn... 
systemd[1]: PID file /var/run/openvpn/openvpn.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN service openvpn.

и в ifconfig виртуальный сетевой интерфейс не поднялся

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25865/discussion-between-alexander-barakin-and-mr-blond97).

Answer (score 1):

собрано из комментариев:

1. не мешает ли *selinux*?
2. существует ли каталог `/var/run/openvpn`? создать:

   ```
   # mkdir -p /var/run/openvpn
   ```
3. *failed to find GID for group nogroup* — вероятно, где-то в конфигурации упомянута эта несуществующая группа. замените на сущствующую нужную.